# Semantic highlighting in Qt Creator not finding some headers

Tags: c++, qt-creator, clang-static-analyzer

I am using Qt Creator on Arch Linux for a plain C++ project. I have enabled the `ClangStaticAnalyser` plugin, but it first complained about missing headers such as `stdio`. After adding `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/c++/6.2.1/` to my `.pro` file, which I am not fond of, since it will break on gcc updates, it stopped complaining about those files, but doesn't seem to be able to find some symbols (almost every symbol, actually).

Screenshot:
[image]

Please do not pay a lot of attention to the code. It compiles fine, but has been hastily converted from C to C++ (hence the `fp` variable name), and was more of a scratchpad-style code.

I am considering disabling the static analyzer altogether, but it would be nice to have it. I tried looking this up online on a variety of websites (including SA) without success.

So, here is my question: how to make those warnings disappear? I suspect that there's something wrong with my Qt Creator/Clang/Project configuration, but I didn't find anything related.

Other question (somewhat related): is there a way to get rid of the gcc version in the project file, to make it more cross-platform?

Comment: OK; I was stuck on this for quite some time, but strangely, closing and reopening the file got me rid of the highlight. There's still the second question, though.